# Related Rates - Ladder Problem

Tags: derivatives, applications

I'm having trouble finding a formula to relate the time with the angle. This is the question:

A $5$ meter ladder rests against a vertical wall at an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal surface as shown below.[image]

The bottom of the ladder is $1$ meter from the wall. If the bottom of the ladder slides away from the wall at a constant rate of $0.5m/s$, at what rate will $\theta$ decrease after $4$ seconds?

My attempt:

$$  \frac{dx}{dt}=0.5m/s  $$
$$  \frac{d\theta}{dt} ?  $$
$$  x=1m  $$
$$  t=4s  $$
$$  cos\theta=\frac{A}{H}=\frac{x}{5}  $$
$$  \theta=cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{5})  $$
$$  d\theta = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}}dx  $$
$$  \frac{d\theta}{dx} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}}  $$
$$  \frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{d\theta}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}  $$
$$  \frac{d\theta}{dt}=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}})(0.5)  $$
$$  \frac{d\theta}{dt}=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{25}}})(0.5)  $$
$$  \frac{d\theta}{dt}=-0.5103m/s  $$

Decreasing at a rate of $0.5103m/s$.

What about the $t=4s$? I'm not sure how to use that because there's no formula that I've learnt that has time and angles in it.

Thanks

Comment: The x in your final derivative is a function of time. x(t=0)=1 does not equal x(t=4). This is where the time dependence comes in. Also, check the sign of your x derivative with respect to time. Is x getting larger or smaller?

Comment: oh right. x is increasing. 0.5 is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, except that you have substituted the wrong value for $x$: You want the derivative at $t=4$, but you have it in terms of $x$; when $t=4$, the value of $x$ is $1 + 0.5 \times 4 = 3$. So plug $x=3$ into your expression for the derivative instead.

<s>Also, your expression for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ has a problem: while you are sliding away from the wall, your value of $x$ is in fact increasing, so you shouldn't put a negative sign in front of the rate.</s> (I see that's been corrected.)

Think of all your variables as a system: when $t$ is some value, then $x$ and $\theta$ take some corresponding value. You've started with $x=1$ when $t=0$; when $t$ changes, so does $x$.

Comment: ahh i see....so that x = 1 is when t = 0. totally missed that....now i understand